# What is a way I can define a range of integers in an if-statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, integer, range

When I try to define an integer or attempt to define a range of integers in an if-statement, it returns an error message saying "Unreachable code"

I've tried a few different methods, such as changing the if-statement to

`if (rand == 33)`

`if (rand.nextInt == 33)`

which returns the error message 
"incompatible operand types Random and Int", "nextInt cannot be resolved or is not a field" respectively.

Then I tried

`if (rand.nextInt() == 33)`

which then spat back "unreachable code".

And for the range issue I tried 33-0, 0-33 which doesnt work.

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Random Integers:"+computeRandom());
}

    public static int computeRandom() {

    //create instance of Random class
    Random rand = new Random();

    //Generate random integers in range 0 to 100

    rand.nextInt(101); //83
    return rand.nextInt();
    if (rand.nextInt() == 33) {

    }
```

I expect it to eventually return the letter "A" depending on what range it falls under at the moment the range is intended to be 0-33.

Comment: You have a `return` statement just before the `if` block. When you execute a `return` from a Java method, the method execution ends from there and returns back to the caller of the method. So your `if` block will never execute, hence the `unreachable code`.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is before the if block, therefore the method will return the value and the if block always won't get called.
The if block should be before the return statement.

For the range verification simply add this if block:

```
Integer val = rand.nextInt();
if (val >= 0 && val <= 33) {
// in range;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return` statement just before the `if` block. When you execute a `return` from a Java method, the method execution ends from there and returns back to the caller of the method. So your `if` block will never execute, hence the **unreachable code**.

For the range check, you can define it as 2 conditions.

1. First condition to check if the value is equal or greater than 0 (`value >= 0`)
2. Second condition to check if the value is equal or less than 33 (`value <= 33`)

Then combine them using AND (`&&`) operator as follows.

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int value = rand.nextInt(101); //83
    if ((value >= 0) && (value <= 33)) {
        // Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `unreachable code` is because your `if` statement is written after the `return` statement.

regarding the range of integers you can always check that a specific value is within this range

```
if (value >= 0 && value < 33){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are *multiple* issues with your posted code, but we can fix them fairly easily. First, your `main()` method currently would only display one value; add a loop - and if you expect to see a letter, then `computeRandom()` should return a `char` (not an `int`).

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Random Integers: " + computeRandom());
    }
}
```

You shouldn't construct the `Random` in your `computeRandom` method, it's highly likely that invoking that in a loop will compute the same *seed* multiple times (so your random numbers wouldn't be random). Construct it once as a `static` field (as here), or pass it as an argument to `computeRandom()`. Next, to test for the range `0 - 33` you only need to test that your value (which you should save, because each call to `Random.nextInt()` *should* return a different value) is less than 34 (since `value` is in the range `0 - 100`). Finally, you should return something when the value is not in the desired range; you want `A` on valid so I chose `B` for not-valid. Like,

```
private static final Random _RANDOM = new Random();

public static char computeRandom() {
    // Generate random integers in range 0 to 100
    int val = _RANDOM.nextInt(101);
    if (val < 34) {
        return 'A';
    }
    return 'B';
}
```

If you didn't know that `value` already had a lower-bound of `0` you would want a logical and with the `if`. Like,

```
if (val >= 0 && val <= 33) {
    return 'A';
}
```